# Encryption export compliance key in plist not read (status is missing compliance in App Store Connect)?

Tags: swiftui, app-store-connect, testflight, watchos

I'm making a watchOS standalone app, Xcode 14.2, watchOS target 9.1.  My app, so far, needs 3 values in the info properties:  ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption = no, and a couple of health privacy keys.

Now, the health privacy keys initially bugged out on upload too, and I figured I had to update my iOS minimum deployment to iOS 15 (seemed the default iOS 13 has some bug or deprecated connection with the info.plist). So I did that, and those privacy keys were uploaded and read correctly by App Store Connect.  I thought this would also resolve the ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption issue, but lo and behold when I upload a build to TestFlight, compliance is still missing.

Can't find any documentation that suggests doing anything more than adding that key, so I'm stumped as to what the issue might be?